# Cannot authorize to Azure API from Azure web application Azure AD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have a web app hosted as an Azure app service that I am trying to authorize to an API also hosted as an Azure app service. I have registered both the app and the API, configured single-tenant AD authentication, authorized the client application, and have successfully obtained a bearer token. However, when I attempt to access a resources I receive a 401 error.

I've tried this using both delegated and application roles with no effect.

EDIT: Here is the code I'm using to obtain the token in my web app:

```
     var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(<clientId>)
            .WithCertificate(<certificate>)
            .WithAuthority(<authority>)
            .Build();

     await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "api://<app_id>/.default" });
```

EDIT: After parsing the JWT token I've confirmed that the application role is present; however the scopes are not. Seems this should not be a problem though.

What are some steps I can take to try to diagnose this authentication problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code for acquiring the token. What are the scopes defined when you acquire the token>

Comment: @GauravMantri - done, thanks! Scopes are currently just user_impersonation

Answer (score 0):

Please check the token used to call the web API. If the issuer has a v2 endpoint, then change "**`accessTokenAcceptedVersion`**" from null to **2** otherwise, keep it `null or 1` .

[image]

**Manifest** in azure ad portal.

[image]

And make sure the scopes are ***granted admin consent*** by admin during authentication or through the portal:

[image]

- 401 error Usually occurs due to audience mismatch.    please check the
  `allowed audiences` parameter from  https://resources.azure.com/  .
- Navigate to your App Service resource > config > authsettings and
  correctly set the AllowAudiences value to the valid ones.
- Audience should client id or app id URI for the app . It is used to
  check if token received is meant for the API you are trying to call.
- AppIdUri of the app can be in the form ***`api://<target_app_id>`*** or
  ***`"https://<site>.azurewebsites.net"`*** And  the  ***`clientIId`*** of theapp.

authsettings  :

```
"allowedAudiences":[
    https://<webapp_name>.azurewebsites.net/,
    api://<target_app_id>,
    client_id
      ]
```

Also tryin above, check scope by removing api:// prefix